# Child element appears even when not hovering on parent

Tags: html, css, hover

On parent element hover, the child appears but when not hovering, the child still appears.

Here's my CSS:

```
.profile-dropdown{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #666;
}

.profile-dropdown > ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.profile-dropdown:hover > ul
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px); 
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 profile-dropdown">
    <p>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Some Text <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As I was saying, I am trying to show child element (ul) on parent hover.

After I hover off of the parent, the child element disappears & again when I try going to parent element the child element shows itself even though I did not hover on the parent element.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a shot descriptive title. Elaborate in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Missing {

```
.profile-dropdown:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px); 
}
```

Works as OP desires: https://jsfiddle.net/f8g7z2wx/

Waiting update of Question...

Comment: Sorry might have missed {, but its in my code. On parent:hover works but it is also working when i hover on the child element which is not visible after my mouse leaves the parent.

Comment: Oh ok, strange, I can't duplicate that with the code you gave...is there any other element on the page with the class .profile-dropdown?

Comment: Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/f8g7z2wx/
Is that performing as you want?

Comment: Yes!Its woeking perfectly. But for some reason its not working on my side :(

Comment: Happy to help debug if you want to share more code. :)

Comment: I solved the issue myself, Thanks anyways Jay A. Little.

Comment: The issue was that the child element was visible in the dom so it, so i removed visibilty & put display none instead.

Comment: Happy you found the problem. You could answer your own question and mark it as correct.